# I want to copy the data folders from a previous ubuntu(14.04) partition

Tags: boot, permissions, hard-drive, data-recovery

My hard drive is a mess and I want to reformat it and do a fresh install of 16.04. My problem is I only have access to the HDD via 16.04 on a USB stick and although I can navigate to the various folders, nothing I do allows me to copy to an external hard drive. The folders are not encrypted. I also have a small swap partition - I would like to preserve the data on that too if possible.

Here's a listing of the home directories on the drive:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /media/*/*/home
/media/ubuntu/0e228f65-dac7-435f-828b-1eb1a6c3f29a/home:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 46 1000 1000 4096 Dec 21  2015 simon

/media/ubuntu/db79a6d1-7c6c-4d8c-822b-ba6ccd1ddecd/home:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 27 1000 1000 4096 Apr 17  2014 simon

/media/ubuntu/ebe2a6ba-9cb5-4279-8352-5082b8dd4d5e/home:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 39 1000 1000 4096 Aug  3 14:21 simon
```

Comment: You must give more details. Specifically, what error do you get when trying to copy the files?

Comment: There is no useful data on your swap. Swap is like RAM, didn't you know?

Comment: You can navigate the internal drive. But can you navigate the external drive? That may be your problem. I believe even if files are encrypted you can still copy them you just can see anything in them without a password.

Comment: @ wjandrea. Specifically "Error while copying -Error opening file: Permission denied" and yes I did know that Swap is just like ram but I'd forgotten!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix .  I can navigate both the internal and external drives and I can copy some files (e.g. .pdf) but not others.  So if I try to copy a directory the directory will be copied but not the contents.

Comment: Are you referring to files in your home directory giving said error? Or system files?

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto.  Just files from my 'user

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto.  Just files from my 'user' sub-directory of the home directory in the 14.04 partition.  My 12.04 partition has nothing left in the home directory and I supposed that the same would happen when I went from 14.04 to 16.04

Comment: Check if it is a permission problem like [the one I described here](http://superuser.com/a/1114160/278831).

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto.  Yes I think it is that, a permission problem. I know the partition is sda4. How do I give myself permissions for that partition or how do I navigate to there and then give myself permissions? Would it be easier to wipe the drive except for sda4, install 16.04 and then transfer the files, or would I still have the same problem?

Comment: See the link above for how to access the drive as root and copy the files. By the way, please update the question with the output of `ls -l /media/*/*/home` from the live DVD/USB after you have mounted the partition. Unless the home is in a separate partition, in which case you should post the output of `ls -l /media/*/*`. This is a wildcard path, please also tell us the full path as well.

Comment: Have done what you asked  and have the output of ls -l /media/*/* but It's about 17000 characters long so I need to print the contents to file and send you the file but I don't know how to do this and  I haven't come up with the answer on the net. Sorry to be such a bore.

Comment: Please tag me: @AndreaLazzarotto otherwise I don't get notified of your comments. :) For long output, use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ then link the output in the question.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Ok so I figured out how to do it. the output is:- http://paste.ubuntu.com/23072968/

Comment: You do not have a separate home partition, but you seem to have 3 Linux systems installed there. O.O Please post the output of `ls -l /media/*/*/home` (it should be shorter).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto.  the output is http://paste.ubuntu.com/23073872/

Comment: @Simon Gatti: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 3):

> I also have a small swap partition - I would like to preserve the data on that too if possible.

There is nothing useful on the swap partition and you don't need to back up that one.

> nothing I do allows me to copy to an external hard drive

This is expected, because the home directory belongs to the user with id `1000` (called `simon`):

```
drwxr-xr-x 39 1000 1000 4096 Aug  3 14:21 simon
```

For some reason you have **3 home directories** but the concept is the same for the other two.

This user does not exist on the live DVD, which you are running as user `ubuntu`. For this reason, the permissions prevent you from loading the contents of the home directory.

You must run the file manager as `root`. I have [discussed this operation on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1114160/278831), so let me just quote my other answer (slightly adapted to your case):

> Run:
>
> ```
> sudo nautilus /media/ubuntu/ebe2a6ba-9cb5-4279-8352-5082b8dd4d5e/home
> ```
>
> On many Linux distributions, you can try to open a directory with the
>   default file manager using `xdg-open` even if you don't know its name:
>
> ```
> sudo xdg-open /media/ubuntu/ebe2a6ba-9cb5-4279-8352-5082b8dd4d5e/home
> ```
>
> Beware: you now have full permissions on the files on any connected
>   drive. Pay attention on what changes you perform.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto.This is what I get but maybe I'm starting in the wrong place!  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23075839/

Comment: @SimonGatti I see nothing wrong there, apart from a couple of Nautilus warning. But why does your output say "script started"? I didn't mention any script, just the command you need to start Nautilus so you can copy your files.

Comment: "script started" is just the output from the 'script' command to give me the output of the terminal as a text file.  I did try to copy files after issuing those commands but still permission denied.

Comment: @SimonGatti I tried the `script` command and it didn't start any file manager after giving it the command. If you need the terminal output, just copy it but run the command **as is.** If you modify it or run it through script or anything else, I am not responsible if it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You miss understand me, I input the commands as you indicated from the relevant prompt. I only used the script command afterwards co get a copy of what happened in the terminal. Anyway I will try again.

Comment: @SimonGatti I see. Just to be clear: you are running my command and you cannot copy files while acting inside the file manager window that appears?