# Recovering data from a laptop that cannot boot

Tags: data-recovery

I have a laptop with Linux Mint installed. I had a power outage, and currently, it cannot boot - it shows `grub rescue` when booting.

I don't mind formatting and re-installing the system, but there are a couple of files which I'd like to recover.

I ran Boot-Info from a live USB, but it didn't help. Here are the logs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23390723/

Can you please help me with this? I'm not familiar enough with Linux to understand much from the logs.

Comment: Hi! You should post your question on our sister-site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/, not on AskUbuntu, because Linux Mint is and unofficial distro so it's off-topic here.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae OP may be using a live Ubuntu USB and thus it would be on topic. But this is actually a duplicate of this Q: http://askubuntu.com/q/813107/271 I can't flag as duplicate because the OP of the other question didn't upvote it. =.=

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto normal upvotes are enough to dupe ;-) Upvoted it and duped it. To others: dont off topic it; dupe trumps off topic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### You must first copy the files to an external storage media first.

1. Boot a live CD/DVD/USB of Linux Mint. You can create a live DVD/CD by burning the iso using Brasero (if using Linux) or WinISO (if using Windows). For making bootable USB you can use UnetBootin (on Linux) or dd cloning (also on Linux) or Universal USB Installer (on Windows).
2. After you have succesfully booted into a live system, plug another external storage (HDD or USB). Next, mount the internal HDD's partitions and copy the required data to external HDD or USB.
3. Now you can install the Operating System on the machine.