# Linux: Recover a faulty system

Tags: boot, data-recovery

**Question:**

I have an SSD with Ubuntu on it, and it seems that the boot sector is faulty.

I **DO NOT** have access to all the files and directories when I use it as a drive on another PC.

Is there a way to maybe get a log of applications installation, so I could recover it to the old state?

OR

Is there a way to fix the faulty boot sector?

**Context:**

I have a PC running Ubuntu, controlling my house.
Naturally, this PC is running 24/7. One day, there were all day power outages, getting the UPS fried, and the PC to not boot.
It said it had no place to boot from, I do not recall the exact error. (Several technicians tried, all failed, on the course of a month, and one of em' fried the motherboard)

Comment: What have yo utried so far?  What errors have you seen?  If yo udon't know the errors, the question is too broad and we will not be able to assist you in debugging.

Comment: I have tried booting from the disk. I failed. "Please enter a proper boot device", no other things. (I am a programmer, not a hardware guy)

Comment: Stop trying booting from the disk or otherwise doing stuff that might ruin it more. First of all, run a live Linux USB/DVD on a working PC, connect the drive through a USB cable/enclosure, then run TestDisk on it. After it is done searching, please post the results shown by the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to copy the data folders from a previous ubuntu(14.04) partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813107/i-want-to-copy-the-data-folders-from-a-previous-ubuntu14-04-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's try fixing your boot first, because that seems to be possible.

First off, grab a live disk and boot from it, into **Try Ubuntu** mode, and open a terminal.

From there, run `fsck` on the Ubuntu partition to see if there are any issues on it. Let `fsck` fix it if at all possible. Example with `/dev/sdb1` being the Ubuntu installer:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
```

If everything's alright and the drive is fixed, you can try running a `chroot` and re-installing Grub to the OS. `sudo -s` into root, and run these commands:

```
cd /
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
```

You will now be in the "broken" Ubuntu install, and will be able to perform operations on your drive. Run the below command to re-install Grub:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

This will re-install Grub to your disk, and hopefully allow everything to work.

**Stop here.** `exit` your chroot, reboot your system and see if it works. If not, then continue.

---

Now, let's also backup your installed packages list and your home folders. Get back into your live disk and chroot

While still in the `chroot`, run this command:

```
apt list --installed > /installed-packages.txt
```

Now, go ahead and `exit` the `chroot` and insert some backup media and mount it wherever. In this example, it will be at `/mount/BACKUP`.

Just run these commands to copy your installed package list and home folders to your backup drive. Also be sure to back up anything else that you need/want stored.

```
sudo cp /mnt/installed-packages.txt /media/BACKUP
sudo mkdir /media/backup/homes
sudo cp -R /mnt/home/ /media/backup/homes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed solution.
I just plugged it in to a live windows PC, just to backup the drive, and I see there are no partitions on the disk. The technician said he does have access to the contents, so I wrongly assumed Ill have too. Ill first look for a solution on partition recovery then.

Comment: @Amit “I just plugged it in to a live windows PC” **Why?** Why Windows? Of course you won't see them listed there. Don't use Windows to perform data recovery *in general* but especially if you want to recover stuff from a Linux disk.